# Magento indexes out of date less than an hour from manual index rebuild

Tags: magento, indexing

All Magento indexes in this particular store we are working on are configured to "Update on save" and very often they will go to "out of date" and some products simply dissappear from the frontend.

Having just performed a manual index rebuild for all affected indexes, in less than an hour the indexes are supposedly out of date again.

I would appreciate any ideas as to what could be causing this erratic behavior.

Comment: No admin products/categories/attributes actions in between? Magento version? What extensions do you have installed?

Comment: @Tim sorry, Magento PE, 1.10.02. heavily customized. No actions aside from adding and editing products, but this should be handled by update-on-save and not invalidate the whole index imho.

Comment: "heavily customized" ... I think you've identified your answer. You are going to have to start disabling modules 1 by 1 until you find your cause. It sounds like you have a rogue extension ...